# Why does signing algorithm in C# give different result than the one in Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, cryptography, webcrypto-api

This is the algorithm for signing the data in C# using a private key from a certificate that is used from both me and the client in order to define an unique key to identify the user:

```
X509Certificate2 keyStore = new X509Certificate2(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Certifikatat\\" + certPath, certPass, X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
RSA privateKey = keyStore.GetRSAPrivateKey();
byte[] iicSignature = privateKey.SignData(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("K31418036C|2022-5-16 13:30:41|406|st271ir481|al492py609|zz463gy579|340"), HashAlgorithmName.SHA256, RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);
byte[] iic = ((HashAlgorithm)CryptoConfig,CreateFromName("MD5")).ComputeHash(iicSignature);
```

I then pass the private key to my Javascript using Bouncy Castle:

```
X509Certificate2 keyStore = new X509Certificate2(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Certifikatat\\" + certPath, certPass, X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
RSA privateKey = keyStore.GetRSAPrivateKey();
var eky = DotNetUtilities.GetRsaKeyPair(privateKey);
Pkcs8Generator pkcs8Gen = new Pkcs8Generator(eky.Private);
Org.BouncyCastle.Utilities.IO.Pem.PemObject pkcs8 = pkcs8Gen.Generate();
PemWriter pemWriter = new PemWriter(new StringWriter());
pemWriter.WriteObject(pkcs8);
pemWriter.Writer.Flush();
return pemWriter.Writer.ToString();
```

This one is the algorithm used in Javascript:

```js
window.crypto.subtle.importKey(
    "pkcs8",
    pemToArrayBuffer(pkcs8Pem), {
      name: "RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5",
      hash: {
        name: "SHA-256"
      },
    },
    false, ["sign"]
  )
  .then(function(privateKey) {
    console.log(privateKey);
    // Sign: RSA with SHA256 and PKCS#1 v1.5 padding
    window.crypto.subtle.sign({
          name: "RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5",
        },
        privateKey,
        new TextEncoder().encode("K31418036C|2022-5-16 13:30:41|406|st271ir481|al492py609|zz463gy579|340")
      )
      .then(function(signature) {
      var iic = md5(signature);
        console.log(ab2b64(signature));
      })
      .catch(function(err) {
        console.error(err);
      });
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.error(err);
  });

function ab2b64(arrayBuffer) {
  return window.btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer)));
}

function removeLines(str) {
  str = str.replace("\r", "");
  return str.replace("\n", "");
}

function base64ToArrayBuffer(b64) {
  var byteString = atob(b64);
  var byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteString.length);
  for (var i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
    byteArray[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
  }
  return byteArray;
}

function pemToArrayBuffer(pem) {
  var b64Lines = removeLines(pem);
  var b64Prefix = b64Lines.replace('-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----', '');
  var b64Final = b64Prefix.replace('-----END PRIVATE KEY-----', '');
  return base64ToArrayBuffer(b64Final);
}
```

The signatures returned are different for some reason. I need them to be the same or else it's all pointless because the client won't be authenticated.

The results are as follow:

```
C#:
57CF663ACBEDE6305309682BA7261412

Javascript:
c099d176dcd95c59d748d6066dcd462e
```

Comment: Please add the different results. Are the real values different or just the encoding (hex, base64...) of the result?

Comment: @jps I added them.

Comment: I know that UTF-8 is backward compatible with ASCII, but maybe it is the source of difference? In C# code you use ```Encoding.ASCII``` and in javascript you use ```TextEncoder().encode``` which uses UTF-8

Comment: @MonsieurMerso I checked both of them and they are the exact same byte array, so that's not what causing the problem.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem using my own pfx/p12 certificate, both signatures are identical! Also, why are your "signatures" so short? With RSA, the signature length is equal to the key length, so for a 2048 bits key, 2048 bits. Furthermore, the values are hex encoded, but the JavaScript code Base64 encodes. You are doing more than you are posting. Please post the *full* code.

Comment: @Topaco I hash them with md5 after i get the signature

Comment: Are the signatures themselves different (using identical encodings)?

Comment: @Topaco The byte arrays are different. I hashed some other values the same way on both C# and javascript and i got the same result. I updated the code and added the 2 hashing algorithms

Comment: The subsequently inserted MD5 line in the Java code generates an exception. Therefore, omit the MD5 hashing for troubleshooting purposes in both codes, so that the problem is not unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244839/discussion-between-bani-and-topaco).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to convert my signature to base64 and then encode it with `atob()` after that i needed [this md5](https://www.myersdaily.org/joseph/javascript/md5.js) library to hash the data and then use `.toUpperCase()` to reproduce the correct result.

The complete code looks like this:

```
md5(atob(ab2b64(signature))).toUpperCase();
```

Now i get the same result from both C# and JS.